# Data binding error in d3:Cannot read property 'start' of undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My data like this:

```
start,end
    2,3
    4,7
    10,14
```

I need to proportional bands that equaled to values. For example, for first values (2 and 3) it must show me between 51°-77° band (max value 14 equal to (2 * Math.PI)= 360°.

But I get an error

```
index.html:37 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of undefined
```

How can I solve this error ?

```
<script>



    d3.csv("StartEndPoints.csv", function (data) { 

    var max = d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.end; })  ;

    var PI = (2 * Math.PI)

        var wid = 960,hei = 500

        var plane = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", wid)
            .attr("height", hei)
          .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(480,250)");   

        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(218)
            .outerRadius(220)
            .startAngle(0)
            .endAngle(2 * Math.PI);

        var arc2 = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(214)
            .outerRadius(216)
            .startAngle  (function(d) { return    (d.start/max)*PI  ; } ) // here i try to normalize the values
            .endAngle    (function(d) { return    (d.end/max)*PI    ; } ) ;

        var group = plane.append("g");

            group.append("path")
            .attr("d", arc)

            group.append("path")
            .attr("d", arc2) 


        plane.selectAll("path")
            .data([data])
            .enter()
                .append("path")
                .attr("d",arc2)


    })
```

Comment: Is the data being loaded properly?

Comment: Yes, i tested. I can creat rectangles with values.

Comment: Looks like `.data([data])` should be `.data(data)`.

Comment: You're using `arc2` without data in `group.append("path").attr("d", arc2)`. You either need to bind some data to that element or define `arc2` so it doesn't depend on data.

Comment: Already I'm working under `d3.csv("StartEndPoints.csv", function (data)` codes, What should I do then ?

Comment: If my comment above doesn't make any sense to you, you can read up on D3's data binding e.g. in [this tutorial](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/binding-data). I don't know what exactly you're trying to achieve with the code.